# Как пользоваться документацией Java API?

Tags: java

Учусь программировать на Java. Уже реализовал какой-то код, основываясь на туториалах, которые встречал в интернете. Т.е. нужна была задача, я искал какие-то примеры и перебирал код, дополняя и изменяя его под свои нужды. Однако при этом с документацией я работал мало. И вот я дошел до того,что мне нужно написать обычный класс, который подключался бы к HTTP серверу(сервер я создал на платформе vert.x, использовав туториал из официальной документации).

Есть в сети туториалы, бесспорно, но мне хочется научиться самому пользоваться документацией (ведь у oracle отличная база данных по всем API) и, основываясь на ней, какие-то вещи писать с нуля. И вот я открываю страницу по websocket API, вижу длиннющий список методов и интерфейсов с классами. А дальше...в общем ощущение,что смотрю как баран на новые ворота,от многообразия разбегаются глаза. Да, я читаю описание методов,но как их друг с другом увязывать я не понимаю. И меня это злит,ибо хочется научиться использовать документацию. Дайте  пожалуйста пару советов,или направление,что изучить.

PS. Небольшое дополнение в предвкушении возможных комментариев:"ээ,да иди в гуггл, ты нуб". Да, я нуб, я это знаю, но я мотивированный нуб, который готов учиться. И хотелось бы услышать совет опытных людей, которые также были новичками и также вникали в это. Спасибо

Comment: У вас правильный подход. Javadoc - это справочник, а не литература. Сначала берете tutorial, user guide, quick start, или что там есть в наличии, и изучаете. Если нужна конкретная информация по API, методам, параметрам, возвращаемым значениям, тогда уже Javadoc. Еще очень полезно бывает посмотреть тесты, хорошие тесты сами по себе документация.

Comment: теперь алгоритм действий есть.большое спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java API в первую очередь помогает при использовании объекта или его метода.
Для изучения библиотеки (да! гуголь вам в помощь) лучше найти обучающую статью.

Для многих библиотек есть User Guide

Посмотрите как это реализовано для библиотек Apache:

- [User Guide](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/description.html)
- [JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html)

Первое для быстрого старта, второе для онлайн-помощи во время разработки.

Answer (score 4):

Документация API это СПРАВОЧНИК для того, чтобы узнать какие методы реализует тот или иной класс и их сигнатуры с возвращаемыми значениями, имеющиеся конструкторы, публичные поля и тп. техническая информация. По документации API еще никто не научился программировать.

Для того, чтобы писать программы нужно научиться способности объяснять машине, что вы от нее хотите, какой при этом использовать язык, это уже дело второе.

Так же, как вы могли бы объяснить, что вы Вася - и французу и эвенку и китайцу при некотором желании, так как обладаете навыками общения между людьми. А вот посмотреть, как по французски пишется какое то слово можно в справочнике - русско-французском словаре, но разговаривать по словарю на французском вы вряд ли научитесь, так как есть, кроме слов, еще синтаксис лексика грамматика и тп. знания. Надеюсь аналогия понятна.

По способности писать программы есть совершенно другая литература, вроде фундаментального труда Николаса Вирта "Алгоритмы и структуры данных". Так же много общей литературы по концепции ООП, архитектуре приложений и тп. Конкретно по Java писали Эккель, Шилдт и прочие заслуженные люди - надо их читать, а в документацию смотреть за справкой по синтаксису, а не по логике и структуре программы.

Answer (score 1):

Имея минимальные знания англо-саксонского можно приблизительно представить какие методы могут быть в изучаемом по документации классе. Например для классов, отображающих что-либо на экране должны быть методы типа `getY()`, `getX`, `setY()`, `getWidth()` etc.

Исходя из этого вы можете начать изучать по документации к-л класс ища предполагаемые вами методы. Остальные можно просмотреть чтобы иметь приблизительное представление о имеющихся возможностях или если ваши предположения о наличии к-л методов не подтвердились.

И в большинстве случаев большинство методов вам либо не понадобятся либо их названия будут столь говорящими, что их описание читать будет и не нужно.